# newentity and patchentities at same time cakephp3

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.x

I want to save and update data at once. In saveMany function.

I have data like

```
[
  [ 
    'id'=>1,
    'name' => 'test1' 
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'test2'
  ]
]
```

if id is there then I need to update the record. Else i need to add the record. How can I achieve this in cakephp 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be worked if you receive data in your post request in same manner or set data in array in same manner.

```
$data=[
  [ 
    'id'=>1,
    'name' => 'test1' 
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'test2'
  ]
];
// In a controller.
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$entities = $articles->newEntities($data);

// if you want to follow transaction manner
$articles->connection()->transactional(function () use ($articles, $entities) {
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $articles->save($entity, ['atomic' => false]);
    }
});

// without transaction manner
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $articles->save($entity);
}
```

Comment: That won't work in most situations, as marshalling the primary key usually isn't allowed, and `newEntities()` will only hydrate, and not merge data, which means that the primary key will be ignored, and you're being left will all new (unpersisted) entites without primary keys, resulting in inserts only. Also validation might not work correctly, as it would be applied in "new" mode, instead of in "update" mode, this even applies when marshalling primary keys would be allowed.

Comment: Long story short, read entities first, and then patch them. When patching, datasets without primary key will be added as new entities.